# Remove fragment and replace a new one

Tags: android, android-fragments

Maybe subject is repeated and there are many topics about that. But I checked all of them and I didn't get the solve.

I have a `fragment` which is inflated on `FrameLayout` and when I click on specific `button` I have to remove current one and replace it with another .. but this process doesn't work. At first the `fragment` inflated as well then we I click on the `button` the `fragment` removed. But another one is created. It doesn't appear on the screen. Although `onCreateView()` method is called.

That's my code:

```
Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(frameId);

 if (fragment != null) {
  mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
  mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(frameId,fragment).commit();
 }
```

Comment: Why remove the fragment?  Just replace it.

Comment: I want to refresh the fragment and I tried to use attach and detach but I faced problem with this technique upon my app. 
If I used replace directly the fragment doesn't call `onCreateView()` method

Comment: What are you doing that would require you to "refresh" a fragment by removing and re-adding it?? In any case this will probably produce a visible "blinking".

Comment: I have an object inside my fragment hold bundle data and I update it from another fragment so I want when I update it the fragment recall `onCreateView()` to replace the previous state with the new one

Comment: also I published asking about the process I follow you can check it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716330/refreshing-for-constant-fragments

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this :: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

Comment: yes Barns I know what you mean but at my app I developed external saver system and connect with fragment life cycle by somehow, because I see setArguments will be not enough to do what I want. I just what to know where's the problem at my code or at the process I mentioned before at the link

Comment: I guess I just don't understand your special case. According to your question, you "click on specific button"... That click is user interaction which creates an event that you can react to. In turn you can refresh you data in your fragment. Even if you are using some "external saver system" there are events that you can react to. I just do not understand what is so special about your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168565/discussion-between-mohamed-nagy-mostafa-and-barns).

Comment: Mohamed, perhaps the accepted answer to this post might help :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722979/implementing-multiple-fragments-in-a-single-activity-dynamically

Comment: Thanks Barns, I used another fragment to handle the process I told you before as the fragment provide method called `setRetainInstance(boolean)` which can used to make isolated from normal fragment behavior .. you can check this source code to .. Thanks again :)
https://github.com/MohamedNagyMostafa/Baking-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/adja/apps/mohamednagy/bakingapp/ui/sys/saver_system/SaverSystem.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is:

1. Retrieving FragmentA from the container.
2. Removing FragmentA from its container. Then committing.
3. Replacing the contents of the empty container (nothing) with FragmentA again. Then committing.

I see two issues here:

1. You're removing the Fragment, committing that (hence the Fragment is now going through the lifecycle methods onStop(), onDestroy(), etc.. ), then you're trying to add it again (in the `replace()` call). You shouldn't add a Fragment that has been removed already, as it will be destroyed by the Activity. This probably explains the stutter you see on the screen; the new Fragment is added to the container just before it's being destroyed.
2. There is no need to `remove()` before `replace()`. `replace()` will `remove()` all Fragments in the container and then `add()` the new one.

---

Solution that illustrates instantiation of new Fragment and redundancy of removal:

```
Fragment fragment1 = getSupportFragmentManager().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
if(fragment1 != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().remove(fragment1).commit(); //Unnecessary, as replace() will remove this anyway. Once we call this, we cannot use fragment1 again as its onDestroy() method is called. 
    Fragment fragment2 = new TestFragment();
    //If we use fragment2 here, the fragment is replaced on the screen. If I use fragment1, the fragment disappears (not replaced). 
    getSupportFragmentManager().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2).commit();
}
```

Comment: amm, I tried to create new instance for a fragment but I get the same result so I don't think that the issues is related to the fragment life cycle.
Also If I used `replace` method directly the fragment will be still as it was, without recall fragment life cycle again as I think this happened because the fragment instance is already existed

Comment: Where are you creating your new instance? I tried your code and when the Fragment is removed it's unable to be used again. I created a new instance within the clickListener and it works; the fragment is replaced on screen: https://gist.github.com/urgentx/8a2fdbbfacddb3afbed07759ddecea78

Comment: when I use new instance and pass specific object to it and pass to replace function this object will be null inside the fragment !! I still don't know the reason of that 
you can check this question, you will understand what i mean
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716330/refreshing-for-constant-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the fragment before trying to replace it.

Also the args to `replace` are `replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)`. From the first line it seems that `frameId` is the id of the fragment you want to replace. `frameId` should instead be the id of your containing `FrameLayout`.

Comment: The frameId actually seems to be correct. findFragmentById() method accepts an integer resource which identifies the container we want to retrieve the fragment from.

Comment: I already replaced it before, the replacing code at `else` statement but I think I don't need to mention its code as It's not important for my problem.